# Using (if,,then,,,if) in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

The following code (not exactly correct code) is written in c++ language.
I'm trying to rewrite it in bash script.

So, if anyone can write it for me, please help..

```
if ( Ipath == null )(
   if( operation == enc )
     Ipath = in.txt;
   else
     Ipath = in.txt.enc
)
```

---

here is what wrote so far, but i think it's wrong

```
if [ "$Ipath" == "$NULL" ]
  then
     if [ "$op" == "enc" ]
        then
            Ipath="in.txt"
     else
            Ipath="input.txt.enc"
     fi
fi
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `$NULL` supposed to be here? Are you trying to check for an empty `$Ipath` variable? Why do you think this code is wrong? Is it not working?

Comment: @EtanReisner,, Yes I'm trying to check if `$Ipath` is empty or not.
Before i wrote these lines, the code was working perfectly !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check, if the result of the interpolation of the variable is empty, which is true if it is empty or if it does not even exist. For this you can use the operator `-z` of `test` (you are using `test` via the brackets):

```
if [ -z "$Ipath" ]
then
    if [ "$op" == "enc" ]
    then
        Ipath="in.txt"
    else
        Ipath="input.txt.enc"
    fi
fi
```

I don't know how you came to use something like `$NULL`. `$` is used in bash as a variable prefix. I suppose you assumed it to be an equivalent of `NULL` in `c`, which is absolutely not the case.

As `NULL` is probably not set, your version should even work, if both `Ipath` and `NULL` are empty. This would however obscure what is intended here.

Please read some introduction to bash programming, like this one:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score 0):

Making the following assumptions

$NULL == null in c++
enc is a variable

```
if [ "$Ipath" == "" ]
then
  if [ "$op" == "$enc" ]
  then
    Ipath="in.txt"
  else
    Ipath="input.txt.enc"
  fi
fi
```

you're almost or already there, what errors are you seeing? If enc is not a variable then remove the $ to make it a string. Null doesn't really exist in bash it's, what you'll likely see is an empty string instead or you may need to check to for whitespace. To be on the really safe side, if $NULL is a variable I would strip whitespace then do the comparison.